# AOP on plain java application

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj

I have successfully use AOP with Spring applications, but surprisingly I stuck on a simple java project. now I'm trying to implement very simple AOP java application, but it doesn't work. Here are basic classes:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MySimpleLoggerAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(TimeableMetric)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("myTrace:before call ");

        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("myTrace:after call ");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}

public class SampleClass {

    @TimeableMetric
    public String doService(String in){
        System.out.println("inside Service");
        return in;
    }
}

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SampleClass().doService("Hello World"));
    }
}


import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface TimeableMetric {

}
```

As you can see it is very simple app with 4 classes. IntelliJ detects AOP advise properly, but it is ignored when I running the app. I'm sure there is a samll mistake which I just can't detect.
Please help!

Comment: You wrote this code and tried to run it (show us how you run it). Why did you write it this way, and run it whatever way and expect it to do what you wanted? (Answers to these questions will indicate that you did some research into using AspectJ.)

Comment: I can write it using aop.xml configuration, but I think it is not mobile. So, I prefer to use annotations to point methods advised methods. Why I implement it this way? Because something similar was working under Spring-boot project. How I run it? From main method.

Comment: So you simply did `java Tester`?

Comment: Yes, just a Java tester.

Comment: Ok. So, in executing the program with `java Tester`, where is AspectJ? What you need to understand is that [annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) do absolutely nothing on their own. They are just metadata. You'll need something to process them. AspectJ typically does this through [load time weaving](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html). Spring AOP uses another approach: proxying. Your program, as you've shown it, has neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is okay, for me the console log looks like this:

```
myTrace:before call 
myTrace:before call 
inside Service
myTrace:after call 
myTrace:after call 
Hello World
```

Probably you are used from Spring AOP to get only one interception for the pointcut `@annotation(TimeableMetric)`, but in opposite to Spring AOP only knowing `execution()` pointcuts, AspectJ also supports `call()` pointcuts. So if you change your pointcut to `@annotation(TimeableMetric) && execution(* *(..))`, the log becomes:

```
myTrace:before call 
inside Service
myTrace:after call 
Hello World
```

As for the question how to get the aspects applied, you need to

- compile the application with the AspectJ compiler *ajc* and then
- run it with the AspectJ runtime *aspectjrt.jar* on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Kriegaex, it was very helpful.
I have configure my IntelliJ to compile using Ajca nd it works perfectly!